# How to make google.com not redirect to my country's local version of Google search?

Tags: google-search, localization

When I try to load `google.com` in my browser (Firefox), Google redirects me to its local version of Google Search for my country:

[image]

Notice how, even though the URL is `google.com`, the page is effectively the one from `google.hr` (Google's Croatian search page). I don't mind the localized UI, the problem is the search results page which doesn't provide the functionality that I'm used to in the English version of Google Search. For example, `define:` searches:

[image]

In the screen shot above, the English version of Google Search is on the left, and my local version on the right. Notice the definition box which is displayed **only in the English version**. I was able to get the English version by adding `?hl=en` to the URL. This is similar to the `ncr` suffix which FYI **appears to have stopped working**.

So, while I can get the English version by using the URL `google.com/?hl=en`, I would like to get it by default for all my searches (including Firefox's search field, for instance).

I've also checked my Google account settings. My language is set to English and no other language is defined:

[image]

Special thanks to Google for wasting my time.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it! The "Search Settings" page is available at this URL:

https://www.google.com/preferences#languages (set to "English")

Google does **not link** to this page from its search start page.

Comment: It actually does, but from the results page—there is a gear icon in the upper-right corner, in line with the links below the search box.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that's how I found it eventually :)

Comment: On this URL I have only "English" selected, yet it still redirect to a country specific site and displays in a foreign language. The /ncr tricks works, on the other hand.