# How to set English and Prevent others in Google when ncr/append-en/... fail?

Tags: google-search, localization

I would like to have my primary language (English) as the main language in Google Searches. 
I know the thread [Setting Google results to stay in a language, regardless of location](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14435/66725) but addresses like `http://www.google.com/en` are redirected wrongly. 
So I would like to prevent all together some languages because they are used wrongly because I have visited such locations sometimes in my past.
Secondary languages ar the following languages in Fig. 1

Fig. 1 Secondary languages in settings, 
Fig. 2 Search results, 
Fig. 3 Settings

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need to stay many days per month in Latvia; and many other countries per month. However, for some reason, Google wants to show me everything in Latvian, although I cannot speak or read it. 
I feel such a behaviour disturbing. I have went through all the language helps of Google, like [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047?hl=en); contacted them unsuccessfully about the case but now also in their official Google Search Forum [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/kVMui1Lo5Ds;context-place=forum/websearch). 
I have seen this behaviour now one year in Google search; here the left-hand-side bar of the Google search after searching "metso kirjasto" in Fig. 2 where the extraction contains .

- Finnish (heading)
- Latvian (most of the parts)
- Swedish (Biblioteka)
- ...

The situation feels more disturbing when Google messes up things with many languages; etc putting here Finnish, Latvian and Swedish together. It would be ok for me if there was no Latvian.

### Search

Searching gives me these parameters in the address bar

- `https://www.google.lv/?`
- `gws_rd=cr%2Cssl&`
- `ei=Ns4PV7OAJebt6QTowrPgCw&`
- `pli=1#` - unknown parameter for instance [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/DGbxPdbNQ94) about *What does &pli=1 parameter (and others) do?*
- `q=metso+kirjasto`

### Search with the extension *Don't track me Google*

You see `pli` parameter is gone but the option `safe=off` as a new one

- `https://www.google.lv/?`
- `gws_rd=cr,ssl&` - google web server redirection country referred and ssl
- `ei=_9APV9D4LIXN6QTSyaToCg#safe=off&` - time of execution and security off
- `q=metso+kirjasto`

Language still stays in Latvian. 
The problem does not seem to be in `gws_rd=cr,ssl&` because google.com/ncr returns the output also in Latvian.

### Search google.com/ncr

Output still in Latvian, like the screenshot above.

### Settings

Settings in Fig. 3 where no Latvian. I have similar settings or only English in other OSes and systems too.

I have removed all my cookies, but it does not solve the problem.

I logged out Stackexchange in all devices. 
The google search "metso kirjasto" returns still the output as described above with most Latvian content.

No VPN.

### Hypothesis about the Problem

I cleared all cookies. I searched "metso kirjasto" and everything was in English. 
I now login to Stackexchange with two-step login. 
I do again the Google Search "metso kirjasto". 
Everything is now like described above: Latvian mesh with Finnish and Swedish. 
I think Google's login system is somehow conflicting here. 
This is not apparently related to third-party cookies because I disabled them but I see the same behaviour still.

I opened a thread about the issue [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/mjOixttxtcA;context-place=forum/websearch) too because the problem is still there.

Hardware: Chromebook 1, Chromebook 2, Asus Zenbook UX303UB
OS: Chrome OS, Windows 10 and all latest distros, OS X all latest versions, Linux Debian 8.5 - 8.7
Internet browsers: Google Chrome 56.x - 57.x, Firefox, Opera, Safari

Comment: Make sure your browser’s language settings are also set to English as the primary language.

Comment: @Alex I have English as my primary language in all browsers of mine.

Comment: Strange. It could be just a cookies issue then. Have you tried removing all of Google’s cookies and see if it still behaves like this?

Comment: @Alex Cookies are not the problem. Cleared them and problem still coming.

Comment: This is really strange. And if you log out from StackExchange? What happens then?

Comment: @Alex See the body. Same output as described above - most latvian content. I logged out Stackexchange in all devices.

Comment: It seems Google knows something you don't. Where is your ISP? Any special setup like a VPN? If you open Google Maps, where does it think you are? And any difference between Google logged in vs. out? And problem exists with both Google direct login and third party site login?

Comment: No VPN. @use3169

Comment: Add the URLs that you wrote in the Omnibox or bookmarks. Also, if you are being redirected to another address add it. This because could be something in the URL that forces that the page be displayed in other than the primary language of your Google account.

Comment: Maybe there are failures on the Google side. Did you already reported this in the [Google Search help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/websearch)?

Comment: @Rubén I opened a thread about this here too https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/mjOixttxtcA;context-place=forum/websearch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Google results to stay in a language, regardless of location](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/setting-google-results-to-stay-in-a-language-regardless-of-location)

Answer (score 1):

Using Google while being signed out will ignore account settings. If are signed in and your main language is not used in [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) try

1. To clear out the cache and cookies
2. Go to http://www.google.com
3. Sign in

Now the Google's home page should be displayed in your option for your account´s main language.

If the above doesn't work for any reason, a way to "force" that the Google's homepage be shown in English is to include the URL parameter `hl=en`. In the case of Google (aka Google Search) try

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en

For other languages, instead of en use the proper language code (`en-uk` for United Kingdom English, `es-419` for Latin American Spanish, `es` for Spain Spanish, etc.)

---

Since 2017 Google no longer redirects users to country domains for several services. Ref. [Making search results more local and relevant](https://blog.google/products/search/making-search-results-more-local-and-relevant/).

Comment: The above settings do not work. I am using two-step verification. Those other variants, I do know, but find them difficult in real life.

Comment: That is weird. Add more details to the question like the URL in the omnibox / address bar.

Comment: Which url do you want? You can choose just google.com and it always go to the language where my IP address is.

Comment: You could add the URL of the source of the screenshots in the question. Usually Google redirects users from a web search result page to another URL including several parameters. See the following question for further details: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22291/turning-off-google-search-results-indirection. The same could happen with other Google services too.

Comment: I think this is the problem of the source `gws_rd=cr,ssl&`. Google always choose country referred option for me although I do not want it.

Comment: Same result with google.com/ncr. Output in Latvian.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Since 2017 Google no longer redirects users of several of their services to their country domains. Ref. [Making search results more local and relevant](https://blog.google/products/search/making-search-results-more-local-and-relevant/). Added this to the answer.