# This is a Google problem, always reverting the language to the location language

Tags: google, localization

This would be a Google problem then.  I think enough people are having this problem and getting so frustrated, me, for one.   I live in Spain, but only speak English.   Furthermore, I have to change my preference daily.  This is not a user-friendly problem, GOOGLE.  It's a Google problem.  Please fix it.  Right now I am trying to put in the tags for this message and Google is guiding me to put in what they want and not what I want which is:  frustrated, annoyed, language, problem, fix

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Google results to stay in a language, regardless of location](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/setting-google-results-to-stay-in-a-language-regardless-of-location)